# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '5.' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I am trying this query but I am getting a conversion error

```
SELECT 
        BANNER = 
        CASE LEFT(PERSONNUM, 2)
            WHEN 01 THEN 'HANNAFORD'
            WHEN 02 THEN 'INDEPENDENT'
            WHEN 03 THEN 'SWEETBAY' 
        END 
FROM VP_ALLPERSONV42 vp
GROUP BY vp.PERSONNUM
```

Comment: `'5.'` isn't an `int` it's a `varchar` representing a `decimal`. You cannot convert such values to an `int`.

Comment: Your value has a trailing dot that is causing the conversion to fail. How do you want to handle this?

Comment: What data type is `PERSONNUM`? If it's a numerical data type, why do you want the "left" 2 numbers (something you would do with strings normally). If it's a `varchar`, why are you storing numerical data in it?

Comment: I don't know why the question was given -2 it is a valid question.

Comment: Likely because we have no sample data and no MVE, @JinThakur , therefore we cannot replicate the error, and can only *guess* at why the OP is getting the error. Which makes the questions difficult to answer and unhelpful to future readers.

Comment: @Lamu Great job Lamu

Answer (score 1):

A total stab in the dark, but you *could* use `CHARINDEX` to see if the `.` is the second character, and then only return the first:

```
SELECT CASE LEFT(PERSONNUM, CASE CHARINDEX('.',PERSONNUM) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
            WHEN 1 THEN 'HANNAFORD'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'INDEPENDENT'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'SWEETBAY'
       END AS BANNER
FROM VP_ALLPERSONV42 vp
GROUP BY vp.PERSONNUM;
```

Returning the first 2 characters seems odd, however, when the values you are checking for are `1`, `2` and `3`; none of which have 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your LEFT(PERSONNUM) is giving numeric values the use [CAST OR CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  functions :

```
CAST(LEFT(PERSONNUM, 2) AS INT)
```

OR :

```
 CONVERT(LEFT(PERSONNUM, 2), '888')
```

Comment: `CAST('5.' AS int)` is still going to error. As will `CONVERT('5.' AS int)`.

Comment: @Larnu this is what I mentioned first in my answer. The OP needs to verify the LEFT(PERSONNUM) result before casting or converting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        BANNER = 
        CASE 
            WHEN LEFT(PERSONNUM, 2) ='01' THEN 'HANNAFORD'
            WHEN  LEFT(PERSONNUM, 2) ='02' THEN 'INDEPENDENT'
            WHEN  LEFT(PERSONNUM, 2) ='03' THEN 'SWEETBAY' 
        END 
FROM VP_ALLPERSONV42 vp
```